# Set default country for the Address type element (Webform)

Tags: webforms

I'm using the webform module (8.x-5.0-rc12) and I've used the *Address* type element to store my addresses.

I'd like to set the *Country* field to default to *United Kingdom* when the form is displayed.

Does anyone konw if I can set that within the user interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the 'Address' element's 'Advanced' tab, you can set the 'Default value' via the UI.

[image]

Comment: To clarify for others in the future you insert the values as YAML, I referred to previous submissions and looked at them in the YAML format to determine what the default value keys should be.  For example ```city: TAMPA
state_province: FL```

Comment: You can use tokens in here too, which is excellent.